# Xpath evaluate only last elements in hierarchy

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

Situation:

```
<div "big page object">
   <div "smaller page object 1">
      <div "smallest page object 1">
         Some text
      </div>
   </div>
   <div "smaller page object 2">
      <div "smallest page object 2">
         Some text
      </div>
   </div>
   <div "smaller page object 3">
      <div "smallest page object 3">
         Some text
      </div>
   </div>
```

I need to check, if at least one of `"smallest page objects"` with text is visible. For example only 2nd one is visible, and I want positive result from action like this:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath ("//div[contains(.,'Some text') and not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]")
```

In this case, it checks `"Smallest page object 1"`, gets that it is invisible, then checks for "Smaller page object 1" and gets that it is visible, so I have positive result on 1st object.

I tried to use `[last()]`, but in this case it takes only `"smallest page object 3"` into consideration.

So I decided to find all 3 smallest objects, put them into array, and figure out which of them is visible using element.displayed property, but if I write:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath ("//div[contains(.,'Some text')]")
```

it puts into array every element of hierarchy.

So is there any conditions to search only for lowest items of hierarchy, without their relatives? Maybe any check that target element has no more  child elements or smth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all smallest object have same hierarchy, then we can try the following x-path.

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath ("//div/div/div[contains(.,'Some text')");
```

if all smallest object have different hierarchy, the we can use the following x-path.

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath ("//div[contains(.,'Some text') and count(*)=0]"
```

It searches for all elements with no child. The we can iterate all list elements to check the visibility using `IsDisplayed` method.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.
And I wonder if I can put something instead of * to check elements without only "div" children?

Comment: please accept my answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for idea. Found more advanced method, based on this.

driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'Some text') and count(*[contains(.,'Some text')]) = 0]"))

Answer (score 0):

I see you are familiar with the .displayed function. I have read, in the past, that a @minimum possibility is there in xpath, but I do not know what this exactly does.

But instead of overcomplicating things, why don't you just make a boolean for every element and check this boolean?

I won't write the code as I don't have a proper IDE here to support me, but what you could do is, you could use:

```
List<IWebElement> someTextElements = 
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'Some text')]"));
```

Then you could check if the list is filled with at least 1. And you could catch the exception with a simple try catch.

Besides this, you could also do a foreach element in the list, do a .displayed check and create some output so you know which element is displayed by getting its parent etc.

Comment: As I said, If I do so, it puts into array EVERY div from page, because every div contains text fom all of its child divs. So even if div in question is hidden, some of its parents are visible anyway, and function does nothing useful.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I didn't quite notice that the div has no identifier. There is no way to get identifiers for the divs? You could try ("//div/div/div[contains(.,'Some text')"), assuming every smallest page object has 2 divs on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this using LINQ.

You can get all the elements that match your locator and then filter that collection down to only those that are visible. Once you do this, you can Assert that the collection is not empty. I'm not sure what assert library you are using, if you are using one, but the code below is using NUnit. If you aren't using an assert library, I would recommend that you do and NUnit is a good choice for C#. If you don't want to use one, you can just verify that `elements.Any()` is `true`. If it is, that means that at least one of the desired elements is visible.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'Some text'))")).Where(e => e.Displayed).ToList();
Assert.True(elements.Any(), "At least one of the elements is visible");
```

BTW, your HTML is not valid so there's probably a better locator but once you get one, this should work.